# how to turn a function from function(element) syntax to $(element).function() syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that accepts the element it needs to operate on as a parameter `element`

```
function changeColor(element){
   $(element).find('.middleBox').each(function(){
       $(this).//do some stuff that does not matter now;
   });
}
```

and I call it this way

```
changeColor($(document)); //this applies it to the whole document
changeColor($('#sectionOne')); //this applies it to only part of the document
```

I want to change it from the format where it accepts its object as a param to this format. How do I do it

```
$('#sectionOne').changeColor();
$(document).changeColor();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nikita said, you need to write a jQuery plugin. Here's a basic example, which should be enough for what you are trying to do:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeColor = function() {
        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).find('.middleBox').each(function() {
                $(this).//do some stuff that does not matter now;
            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I agree with your above answer. But what, If i'm not interested to use jquery into my project then? Actually I'm using Angular JS. Waiting for your reply...

Comment: @vijayshegokar I recommend that you create a new question so that people can get points for answering it.

Comment: I have created a new question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504841/how-to-create-a-function-on-html-element-instead-passing-element-as-parameter

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a jQuery plugin. jQuery folks provide [a tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for that.

If you don't like reading much, you can practically copy-paste [maxHeight example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#The_Basics) and replace logic inside.