# How to create a function on HTML element instead passing element as parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that accepts the element as a parameter, this element will used to perform operations inside function.

```
function center(element) {
   // code to align this given element to center position
   element.css("position","fixed");
   element.css("top", Math.max(0, ((window.innerHeight - element[0].offsetHeight) / 2))+ "px");
   element.css("left", Math.max(0, ((window.innerWidth - element[0].offsetWidth) / 2))+ "px");
   return element;
}

// calling above function
center(element);
```

Here element is passed as parameter. But I don't want to do that. Is it possible to create a function which will be called on element? Example

```
element.center();
```

You can also consider jQuery functions like: `$(element).next();` etc.

Note I don't want to use jQuery. I need pure javascript coding.

By using jQuery it can be possible by creating below

> center function

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2)   + $(window).scrollTop())+ "px");
   this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft())+ "px");
   return this;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a function to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) object:

```
Node.prototype.center = function() {
    // code to align this given element to center position
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, ((window.innerHeight - element[0].offsetHeight) / 2))+ "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, ((window.innerWidth - element[0].offsetWidth) / 2))+ "px");
    return this;
}
```

This will allow you to call `.center()` on any node.

**Note:** When defining prototype functions, `this` is the object (in this case a Node) on which the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a prototype named `center` to your `element` object, you will be able to call the `center` method on `element`.

## References

**Prototypes in Javascript**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype